# MVC solution becomes unresponsive

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building a solution using asp.net MVC and it is my first time doing so.

**The problem**

After the solution has been running for some time the controllers become unresponsive. The client side works fine, and when calling a controller using ajax, the controller begins excecuting, but whenever it hits the first line it stops excecution. The ajax call is still waiting for a responce, and I am able to make a new request (that also stops). It does not throw any errors, it just stalls. This happens both when debugging or "start-without-debugging".
Entity framework is used within some of these controller methods for database calls, if it has anything to do with the error.

I am suspecting that one of these things must be done, but I am not certain at all:

- Is this only an issue because I am using localhost?
- Are there some settings describing maximal runtime? Is there a specific thing
- I must do whenever a controller is called?
- Does the database has anything to do with the stalling?

I am not sure what code to attach, since this error seems to happen after some time, and not specific to a controller or method. Let me know if there is something you want to see.

**Edit**
I'm adding one ajax call as example, but note that the ajax call is working. It is the controllers (Not only RemoveTest-controller) that stalls and only after debugging for some time.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/RemoveTest/RemoveByPlacement",
    data: { input: someInput},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

**Edit 2**
I should maybe say that it is not only happening when using ajax. The problem also happens when opening a new page, since this also needs execution from a controller.

**UPDATE**
This may be an issue with the database. I have inserted var a = 10; to my controller, and this is getting executed. But it stops after trying to execute the line after.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RemoveById(string id)
    {
        var a = 10;
        TestReciving test = db.TestRecevings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        Placement placement = db.Placements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestRecivingIdRef == id);

        ...

    }
```

**UPDATE**
I did what Mark Homer said. Even though this had to be fixed, it did not solve my problem. When running in IE I get a HTML1300 (navigation occurred) message when changing page, but when it halts and I try to open the file I get "http://localhost:51140/Account/Login could not be opened". It seems to me that IIS Express stops responding, even though it keeps running.

The controller looks like this now:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveById(string id)
{
    using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        TestReciving test = db.TestRecevings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        Placement placement = db.Placements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TestRecivingIdRef == id);

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing your code helps - Probably the ajax call is best. You know, where it stops executing

Comment: I've edited with example.

Comment: Thanks, can you also post the controller method? And what is someInput supposed to be? A string etc

Comment: Do you use Local IIS or IIS Express? Did you try to restart IIS?

Comment: Atre you debugging when it becomes unresponsive?

Comment: I am using IIS Express. I'm guessing (correct me if i'm wrong) that when I stop debugging and then starts it again, that IIS has been closed and restarted. I am having this issue every day, so restarting is probably not a valid solusion. I have not made any settings to IIS. It is what "came with" VS15.

Comment: What do you mean by alte @Liam? Altering code? Setting break points? Yes and yes, if that was what you meant.

Comment: Are you using `test` and `placement` again and again futher in you code??

Comment: sounds like database request is timing out or just not responding, also looks like you are leaving the db context open. You should use USING to open and close the context for each use not leave open. Try replacing with returning a simple string without database request and see

Comment: Thanks @MarkHomer. That was probably causing some inconsistency. I've updated my question, since it did not solve the stalling. :(

Comment: Is the `db` field/property a Entity Framework `DbContext`? If so, where do you create the instance and when do you dispose it?

Comment: @bassfader: Yes it is a DbContext. I've updated the question with the changes from Mark Homers comment.

Comment: you're calling RemoveByPlacement but your action is RemoveById. Also as i suggested just try returning string from your action without DB use and see if working,

Comment: Thanks again @MarkHomer. I have posted the wrong method, but as already said is this not an issue only when using ajax or with this controller specific and the ajax is working multiple times before the whole site goes idle. I am getting the required string that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it to work. The issue was a two-headed giant which was why I had troubles pinning it down.

**First issue**
Mark Homer said to use `using` when I used the database. I did this and while it solved a subset of the issue, it did not solve it completely. But from this day I will remember to use `using`.

**Second issue**
I was not able to track it down to something specific, but I created a new project and moved my files into it (except the auto generated once). Since doing this have have not been able to reproduce the problem. I tried using GitHub to find differences in the two solutions, but only to find that the non-working project had different framework versions. It really bugs me, that I can not pin down the reason, but at least it works.

Thanks for your responses, guys.